# Drush does not recognize an env variable with Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, drush

In a PHP / Drupal project I'm encountering a problem when using Drush in a Heroku instance. The environment variable `DATABASE_URL` in the `settings.php` file is not recognized by Drush.

However, when I use the command `heroku config -a my-app -s` the `DATABASE_URL` is visible. Same with `phpinfo()`.

I try to use `Procfile` like:

```
web: export DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL && heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

but that doesn't work, either.

The only way to get Drush to recognize the variable is to execute `export DATABASE_URL="mysql://..."` when I am on the instance, but it's not persistent:

```
heroku ps:exec -a my-app
export DATABASE_URL="mysql://..."
drush status
```

Any suggestions?

`settings.php`:

```php
$db_cred = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => ltrim($db_cred['path'], '/'),
  'username' => $db_cred['user'],
  'password' => $db_cred['pass'],
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => $db_cred['host'],
  'port' => $db_cred['port'],
  'isolation_level' => 'READ COMMITTED',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\mysql\\Driver\\Database\\mysql',
  'driver' => $db_cred['scheme'],
  'autoload' => 'core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/',
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is by design](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#environment-variables):

> The SSH session created by Heroku Exec doesn’t have the [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) set as environment variables (i.e., `env` in a session doesn’t list config vars set by `heroku config:set`).

I suggest you connect using [`heroku run`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run) instead:

```
heroku run bash -a my-app
drush status
```

The main difference between `heroku ps:exec` and `heroku run` is that the former connects to a running dyno and the latter spins up a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos).

You should also roll back that change to your `Procfile`. There's no point in re-exporting an environment variable like that, and it may be confusing later.

Finally, note that the value of `DATABASE_URL` can change at any time. Even if you were able to export its current value in a persistent way, that connection string might not work tomorrow. It's better to read the variable every time.

---

Side note: [It doesn't look like `drush status` is a valid command](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/all/). I'm not a Drupal guy so can't help much beyond pointing that out. Maybe you're looking for `core:status`, `config:status`, or another similarly-named command?

Comment: Thanks, it's works ! `drush status` is an alias for `drush core-status`